# How to cast between types

Tags: rust

Was trying to write a generic function wich fills Vector in range

```rust
fn fill_vec<T: From<usize> + Copy>(target: &mut Vec<T>, to: usize, step: usize) {
    let mut start  = 0_usize;
    for i in 0..to {
        if start >= to {
            break;
        } else {
            if start > 0 {
                target.push(T::from(start));
            }
            start += step;
        }
    };
}
```

But I got the error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `i32: std::convert::From<usize>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:28:14
fill_vec(&mut target, 30, 4);
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<usize>` is not implemented for `i32`
```

Comment: Can you try `fill_vec(&mut target, 30 as usize, 4 as usize)` ?

Comment: The same thing.

Comment: The error says it, `i32` does not implement `From<usize>`, because `usize` has a bigger range, and `From::from` is infallible. Would you consider using `TryFrom<usize>`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with the minimal code necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: @rodrigo 
It works. Thanks.
I thought about it too. That this could be the reason.
But i was confused cuz this function works. I thouth numbers are have i32 type by default.

```rust
fn adds<T, R>(x: T, y: R) -> T where T: Copy + From<R> + Add<Output=T>, R: Copy {
    x + T::from(y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you cannot implicitly convert from `usize` to `i32`.
For this kind of cast (which could lead to truncation) you
need the `as` keyword.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    let a: usize = 123;

    // v.push(a);
    // expected `i32`, found `usize`

    // v.push(i32::from(a));
    // the trait `std::convert::From<usize>` is not implemented for `i32`

    v.push(a as i32); // cast
}
```

About your specific example, the `num_traits` crate might help.

```rust
fn fill_vec<T: num_traits::cast::FromPrimitive>(
    target: &mut Vec<T>,
    to: usize,
    step: usize,
) {
    let mut start = 0_usize;
    for i in 0..to {
        if start >= to {
            break;
        } else {
            if start > 0 {
                target.push(T::from_usize(start).unwrap());
            }
            start += step;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for answer.

Comment: Sorry. Can't vote for your answer.

Comment: @Khatry no problem, don't worry.